# How do I drop rows from a Pandas dataframe based on the maximum value of the whole row?

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to drop rows based on a conditional of the maximum of *all* the values in the row, not on a column by column basis like most of the solutions on this site demonstrate.

Let's say I have the following dataframe:

|  | AA | BB |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 5 | 8 |
| B | 11 | 55 |

I want to drop all the rows where the maximum value of the row is <= 50. So row A should be dropped since the max value in the row is only 8.
How do I go about doing this?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You seem to be asking for someone to write some code for you. Stack Overflow is a question and answer site, not a code-writing service. Please see [Ask] to learn how to write effective questions. And explain what you have tried so far.

Comment: `df[df.gt(50).any(axis=1)]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `drop` Pandas function for instance :

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'AA':[5, 11],
                   'BB':[8, 55],
                   })


df = df.drop(df[df.max(axis=1) < 50].index)

# >>> df
#    AA  BB
# 1  11  55
```

Comment: Or with ```lt``` contrary of ```gt``` : ```df.drop(df[df.max(axis=1).lt(50)].index)```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of dropping rows, you can keep right ones:

```
>>> df[df.max(axis=1).gt(50)]
    AA   BB
B    11  55

# Or suggested by @BigBen
>>> df[df.gt(50).any(axis=1)]
    AA   BB
B    11  55
```

Comment: Very good with ```gt``` instead of signs